# What proving technique to use for this inequality?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

Prove there exists no positive integer n such that $[2n+1] < [(n+1)^2−4] < [3(n+1)]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by expanding out the polynomial:

$\begin{align}
2n + 1&< n^2 + 2n + 1 - 4 < 3n+3\\
\Rightarrow 2n + 1&< n^2 + 2n - 3 < 3n + 3\\
\Rightarrow 1 &< n^2 - 3 < n + 3 \\
\Rightarrow 4 &< n^2 < n+6 
\end{align}$

The smallest integer with $n^2 > 4$ is $n = 3$, and $n^2 = 9 < 9$ is a contradiction. Integers larger than $3$ will run into the same problem, as $n^2$ will grow faster than $n$.

Comment: Thanks for this! Is this a form of direct proof or proof by contradiction?

Comment: It can be framed either way. Many direct proofs can be phrased as proofs by contradiction (not the other way around, though!). For example, one could prove that $n<n+1$ by assuming it’s not true, subtracting $n$ from both sides, and arriving at a clear contradiction. One could also phrase a proof of that directly.